# playing a sound when condition becomes true in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

i want to make label that have text , and when the label becomes to the text that i want , 
i want a sound to be played one time only

i mean that i have a button that when clicked it checks the the label text and if the label text is the one i want it plays sound (the sound time doesn't exceeds 2 seconds)

this is the interface section (viewController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *label;

}

@property (nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

-(IBAction) checkLabelText:(UIButton *)sender;

@end


this the implementation section (viewController.m)

#import "viewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize label

-(IBAction) checkLabelText:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([label.text isEqualToString:@"hi world"])
    {
        //i want the code of playing the sound here
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Do you want the code?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: i want the framework or the class that i can work with

Comment: Ok I just posted an answer. If you have any questions please ask

Comment: thanks, for answering me , and thanks for telling me about the mistake in my code (in if blocks) ,i fixed it , this is my first question in stackOverFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all the if-statement is supposed to be like this:

```
if([label.text isEqualToString:@"hi world"])
{

}
```

Next if you want to play audio do this:

```
if([label.text isEqualToString:@"hi world"])
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yourSound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    self.audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [self.audio play];
}
```

and in your `@interface`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audio;
@end
```

If you have any questions do not be hesitant to ask.

-Abdullah Shafique